# How to read files on App Engine using /tmp/? I get [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I've been developing a Flask App and it works perfectly. I was going to upload my app to Google's App Engine but I'm having troubles.
I need to read a file in order to create a Google's API service, I'm using /tmp/ for reading it but it won't work. The file is token_sheets_v4.pickle. Here's the code that reads the file:

```
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open('/tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Specially, this part is giving me trouble (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle'):

```
        with open('/tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)
```

I already tried putting this info on `app.yaml` but I only get the file(token_sheets_v4.pickle) downloaded when I go to my app

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: token_sheets_v4.pickle
  upload: token_sheets_v4.pickle
```

I would hella thankful if someone could help, Thanks

Comment: Where does the `token_sheets_v4.pickle` file come from?  If it is a constant that doesn't change, then you can upload it with your source code and read it from there.  If it is something that changes, then you probably need to store it in datastore or google cloud storage.

Comment: ```token_sheets_v4.pickle``` doesn't change is constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a while struggling with this problem I found that the smartest solution was to **read the docs** of Google App Engine, just as user nocommandline suggested.
Reading the docs helped me understand that GAE works with environments that run your app properly, by "properly" I mean that you can run apps without setting an specific environment but having done that gaves you more options, such as in this case, reading/writing files. From my understanding I see environments as a set of attributes to run an app on GAE. Environments are for determine a specific amount of resources that your app will be allowed to used, for example timeouts on http requests.
And, how do you set an environment anyway?
Accoding to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables) (python) you must set your environment (standard or flexible) on your `app.yaml` file.

I found that my best option was the standard environment, so mi final code was:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -t 3600 -b :$PORT main:app

env_variables:
  GAE_ENV: "standard"
```

For reading I no longer needed `tmp`, but for writing I used `tmp`.
**If you can't understand my answer feel free to leave a comment**

Answer (score 0):

Since you are treating token_sheets_v4.pickle as static file, I believe your app.yaml file should have been something like

```
- url: /tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle
  static_files: token_sheets_v4.pickle
  upload: token_sheets_v4.pickle
```

But even the above is wrong because the `/tmp/` is a temporary directory. As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files) says - All files in this directory are stored in the instance's RAM, therefore writing to /tmp takes up system memory.

So in the end, I think your `app.yaml` should actually be

```
- url: /token_sheets_v4.pickle
  static_files: token_sheets_v4.pickle
  upload: token_sheets_v4.pickle
```

and then your code should be reading the file directly and not referring to `/tmp/`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I just tried this solution but I get the same error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle'.
This is my code:
```if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open('/tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)```
```runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
handlers:
- url: /token_sheets_v4.pickle
  static_files: token_sheets_v4.pickle
  upload: token_sheets_v4.pickle```

Comment: No, my solution is that you should not be using ```/tmp/``` since you are uploading the file as a static file. My solution says to make your app.yaml like the example in the lower part of my response and to not read from ```/tmp/```

Comment: Okay, so this is my new code:  ```with open('token_sheets_v4.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)``` and app.yaml: ```runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
handlers:
- url: /token_sheets_v4.pickle
  static_files: token_sheets_v4.pickle
  upload: token_sheets_v4.pickle
```,
but now i get [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'token_sheets_v4.pickle'

Comment: Please read my last comment again. You can't do what you are doing if you have your file as a static file. Later in the day, I'll try to see if I can lay hands on a sample code for what I think you want to do or maybe someone will provide an answer for you before then

Comment: Okay, but I can't seem to understand what a static file is. Is a file that I upload to App Engine? Thanks for your help

Comment: See this link for static files - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files

Comment: So static files are files to be consulted during the execution of the app. According to that I think that 'token_sheets_v4.pickle' is a static file. Am I right? How can I read a static file then?

Comment: Stackoverflow guidelines discourages extended discussions via comments and unfortunately, I can't move this to chat (you don't have enough points to start a chat). You need to first get some basic understanding of how GAE works. Go to their home page and read about it. You should also make sure GAE Flex is your best solution (check if you're better off with GAE Standard). We also plan to start a blog series in the near future explaining the basics of GAE so keep an eye on our website - https://nocommandline.com. You can also check it for other types of help

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a static file to do this.  Put the file `token_sheets_v4.pickle` with your code and when you deploy your code, this file will also be uploaded.

Your Python code can then open this file the same way that you open any other file.  One helpful trick is to use the `__file__` attribute of a Python file to help in specifying the path to the file.

Suppose that the file is in the same directory as `code.py`.  In `code.py`, You can open the file like this:

```
fn = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/token_sheets_v4.pickle"
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    ...
```

I do this frequently and it works great.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already uploaded ```token_sheets_v4.pickle``` along with my code and I tried to open it like this ```with open('/tmp/token_sheets_v4.pickle', 'rb') as token:``` but I get [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'token_sheets_v4.pickle'. What do you mean by "using the ```__file___``` attribute? Thanks

Comment: @junietoc, This file is not in the `tmp` directory.  I'll update my answer with more details.