# Trying to pick up a value from an executable file using Python on the Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a Python app on the Google App Engine which runs a compiled executable file from C++ code - which I need the Python app to read.

I am able to run the executable on Python and extract the value I need when running locally. However, my solutions do not work on the app engine.

I will highlight my attempted solutions below, which have worked locally but do not work on Google's App Engine.

NOTE: Just to be clear, I compile the C++ code locally and upload the executable to the cloud (not the C++ code).

**Attempted Solution 1**

The [App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-temp-files?tab=python) states that we can utilise the `/tmp` folder to create and read temporary files.

My C++ script writes the required values in `/tmp/results.txt`:

```
// my_script
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("/tmp/results.txt");
myfile << value;
```

and the my Python file reads the newly created txt file:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["./my_script", "arg1"])
with open("/tmp/results.txt", "r") as file:
```

This solution works fine locally, however, does not work on the cloud - I get the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/results.txt'
```

I think the reason this has not worked is because the documentation that I provided above states this this is a method for *Python* code to write temporary files (not executables).

**Attempted Solution 2**

My second solution utilises `subprocess.Popen` to read the output from the compiled C++ code.

My C++ code now simply does this:

```
// my_script
std::cout << value;
```

and my Python code reads the output with

```
import subprocess
exe_var = subprocess.Popen(["./my_script", "arg1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
value_var = exe_var.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").split()
```

Again, this solution works fine locally, but does not work on the Google App Engine - as `value_var` is empty.

Are there any other viable solutions to get this functionality to work? Or perhaps amendments to my proposed solutions?

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python310
service: default

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
  - url: /exe
    static_files: exe/main
    upload: exe/main
  
entrypoint: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 server:srv
```

Comment: FYI, your issue has nothing to do with C++.  Executables don't care about what their source language was.  The executable can be generated by LISP or FORTRAN, but still must be compatible with the EXE file format.  I recommend removing the C++ tag.

Comment: 1) When your ran your App locally, did you run it with ```dev_appserver.py```? That's the only way to try to simulate actual GAE prod env (it's not exact but it's the closest). Running with say ```python main.py``` can be significantly different from GAE prod. 2) You can try running the c++ code with [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) which will wait for the command to complete before returning output.

Comment: @NoCommandLine thank you - I haven't run it with `dev_appserver.py`, I think I will try get it set up because deploy everytime I make a slight change is quite time consuming. As for using `subprocess.run`, I tried what you said with arguments `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `capture_output=True`, but they still return an empty output unfortunately.

Comment: What is strange is that the app engine it seems to be running the executable fine (as in, it doesn't error), but it just just won't pick up the output.

Comment: What does Cloud Logging show? Is the executable even running? On what type of machine was the code compiled on? Unless a C/C++ program is linked statically, the program will require library modules (DLLs, .so, etc). My guess is the program is failing to start and you will see an error in Cloud Logging.

Comment: @JohnHanley The thing is, it doesn't throw an error - it just returns an empty list after running the executable.

Comment: Did you check Cloud Logging? If your program cannot run, it cannot return an error. Also, provide details in your post for my other questions.

Comment: Ah yes, I have checked the Cloud Logging - no error was thrown in relation to the script, it's as though it ran with no issues. The app runs fine, it's just a component (a radio button to be precise) the should produce some numerical values (and I have some exception handling when it returns nothing). I have included my `app.yaml` in my original question - I didn't previously link the executable as a static file there but I am now starting to think this might have something to do with the issue

Answer (score 0):

By default, your application code cannot access any files that are part of the static content of your app (i.e., those that match a static_files or static_dir handler configuration pattern). Setting the [`application_readable: true`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element) option for the corresponding `app.yaml` handler configurations is required if you want to access the file.

> **application_readable**
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file handlers
> are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users. They cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data storage resource quotas.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer - I tried to include `application_readable` but I get the following error: `This field is not configurable with runtime [python310] since static files are always readable by the application`. For reference, I have include the code for `app.yaml` in the question

Comment: @Naji I apologize for not mentioning that, `application_readable: true` is deprecated for latest runtimes. Can you try reading `results.txt` instead of `/tmp/results.txt` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67913918/18265570). And may I know why you are not including `results.txt` path under `static_file`

Comment: @Naji, let me know if the above suggestion helped? if not, we can solve further